# Android make an activity pause running when it is not in the front of the stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which holds a fragment called paymentfragment, paymenfragment holds all the cards a person has.  Then I have an activity called addcardactivity which is where a user can add cards.  There is a button on the paymentfragment which takes the user to the addcardactivity, but when they are done adding their new card I want the user to go back to the paymentfragment and I want the payment fragment to refresh so that it can hold the new card.

The way I am doing, it is not to end the paymentfragment, and once the addcardactivity is done i finish that activity, the only problem is then it does not refresh.

This is the relevant code from the paymentfragment

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddCardActivity.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now ideally, under the startactivity, i would run the method refreshtasks();
however that doesn't work because it just runs it too early.

Any ideas?

Comment: *make an activity pause running when it is not in the front of the stack* this is default behavior

Comment: Why don't you take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html meanwhile you can instead put your refreshtasks() in onResume of the paymentFragment.

Comment: thanks the onResume was just what I was looking for, will also check out that link thanks so much